# How can I use my custom class in a view on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a custom class that I have to use inside my view. But how I do this?

In Laravel 4.2, I simply run `composer.phar dump-autoload` and add in `start/local.php` as follow:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/helpers/MyClass',
));
```

Finally, inside my view, I just use my class: `MyClass::myMethod()`. Again, how I do this with Laravel 5?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have two options, make a `Service` or a `Service Provider`.

#### Service

This class could works as a helper having all its methods statics. For example, in app/Services folder you can create a new one:

```
<?php
namespace Myapp\Services;

class DateHelper{
 
    public static function niceFormat(){
        return "This is a nice format";
    }

}
```

Then, add an alias to this class at `config/app.php` like so:

```
'DateHelper' => 'Myapp\Services\DateHelper'
```

Now, In your application you can call the `niceFormat()` method like `\DateFormat::niceFormat();`

#### Service Provider

In the other hand, you can create a Service Provider like the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers) state and attach a [Facade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades).

Answer (score 6):

I just found that you can add any class instance to a view by simple injection.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#service-injection

Just create a class like:

app/Containers/Helper.php

```
namespace App\Containers;

class Helper {
    function foo() {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
```

In blade view file:

```
@inject('helper', 'App\Containers\Helper')

<div>
    What's Foo: {{ $helper->foo() }}
</div>
```

And, that's it! Isn't that so cool!