# Laravel 5 accessing custom functions in a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to make it possible to add custom functions that I can use within a view. For instance I want to make it possible to call a function that will display data. I do not want to do this from the controller as I'm trying to make this as customisable as possible.

Apparently someone sent me information on possible creating a service provider and injecting this into the base of the app?

Comment: What kind of data would that function display? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: May be view composer can help you ?
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers

Comment: Laravel 5 doc -> http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers

Comment: You can create a Helper class like this way:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371697/how-can-i-use-my-custom-class-in-a-view-on-laravel-5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a custom helper function directly in `bootstrap/app.php` but there are better ways.

If you just want simple functions like [Laravel's helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers), create a `helpers.php` file in your app directory and require it in your `bootstrap/app.php` file, then you can create all the custom function you want in it, for example:

```
<?php

function coolText($text) {
    return 'Cool ' . $text;
}
```

and call it in your view:

```
<div>{{ coolText($someVar) }}</div>
```

---

For something more advanced you can create a Helper class in your app directory, bind it in your `AppServiceProvider.php` and add any method of your choice in this class.

app/Helpers.php

```
<?php namespace Helpers;

class Helpers
{
    public function coolText($text)
    {
        return 'Cool ' . $text;
    }
}
```

You can inject this class in your view or create a [Facade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades) for this class to access it in your view:

```
<div>{{ Helpers::coolText($someVar) }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this and it works first time. You sir are a legend.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, mark this question as acceptable using the check symbol, It will mark your post as answered.

Comment: If my function is a get method i.e:, `public function getReviews()` how could I retrieve it in my view..??!!

Comment: please add the static keyword like `public static function coolText`