# where to put global "use" php in laravel 5.4 (Facade on the fly laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel

in laravel 5.4, we dont need to create any facade class again to create our own custom facade. we only need to prefix our class namespace with "Facades" to make it Facade.

for example:
`use This\Is\Original\Namespace` becomes `use Facades\This\Is\Original\Namespace`.

What I want to ask is where is the right place to put that `use` so our object is callable from any blade view?

I have tried to put it in service provider and controller but I keep getting this error:

`Class 'MenuGroupHelper' not found`.

but it works when I use it like this in my view:

```
<?php
use Facades\Omoikane\Services\MenuGroup\MenuGroupHelper; 
{{ MenuGroupHelper::myMethod() }}
?>
```

I tried the link that guy mark this question duplicate and add this to to app aliases

```
'MenuGroupHelper' => Facades\Omoikane\Services\MenuGroup\MenuGroupHelper::class,
```

but still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28372119/7377984

Comment: does that mean i need to create facade class ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to create the facade, nor should you have to add it to the app aliases. The whole point is to have magic foo, without config or additional code. What code are you using in your SP and/or controller? Which specific version of laravel are you using?

Comment: it is on the title 5.4

Comment: Have you tried to add an alias for it in the config/app.php? It should work even not for facades.